# Database is not persisted in pv

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I am trying to write some data on a PersistentVolume in a Kubernetes cluster. I've chosen a mysql database for this purpose (I've also tried with a postgres already, also didn't work - the database technology is not important for me here).

I'm applying the pv, pvc, then the deployment. Pv and Pvc are bound, pod is up and showing no error regarding being able to connect to the pvc, so it should be working. Exec into the pod, create a new database, create a table, insert some data. Then delete the deployment, create it again, then exec into the pod and the database is gone. What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't the database be persisted in the pv?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:8.2
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pvc
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100M
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/data/
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100M
  storageClassName: standard
```

Comment: If the new Pod isn't scheduled on the same node as the original pod, the `hostPath` volume will misplace your data.  I'd recommend not manually creating the PersistentVolume at all, but rather letting the cluster's storage provisioner manage this for you.  Even consider using a StatefulSet rather than a Deployment, which will also embed a PVC template.

Comment: I'm testing locally with a kubernetes cluster on docker-desktop. There's only one node.

Answer (score 0):

Include `volumeName` to your `PersistentVolumeClaim`

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: "Standard"
  volumeName: mysql-pv
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
```

I would suggest alo to use [`statefulset`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/stateful-workloads/mysql#deploy-statefulsets) and apply [`PodDisruptionBudget`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/stateful-workloads/mysql#pdb) for more steady operation of your mysql app.